# How to write a code for total count in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, activerecord-calculations

I have a variable where i will get the total count and i want to reduce the total count by 1 and then i need to pass the reduced count to the total count variable.

i have tried like count = count-1 and this wouldn't worked for me.

EX: I have a variable call count = 15
 for one scenario like in loop or something i need to check like if the count = 15 decrements that count to 14 and assign that 14 value to the count variable, so based on that value i can process my application.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Start by doing it without the loop. Decrease by one, display the value, decrease by one, display the value, ect... when this is working, look at how it could be used in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you define the variable outside of the loop:

```
Dim count As Integer = 15

While count > 0
    count -= 1
End While
```

But you can also use the variable directly on a `for` loop:

```
For count As Integer = 15 step -1
    'use the variable
Next
```

Comment: I have declared two variables like Count and Count1
I have already variable which will give the total count and i can use you code like  
            
While count > 0
    count -= 1
End While

and i am trying to write the condition like 
if count <>count1 then
Exit Sub
End if

Will this condition works for me.